# local storage object named with array

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

I am trying to access native storage, I just need to transfer data from one storage object to other, were i added its reference name into an array, because the same process would get repeated again and again.

```
    shiftingSequence(){ 
    for (var index = 0; index < this.nextMonth.length; index++) {

        this.nativeStorage.getItem(this.nextMonth[index]).then(
            data =>{
                console.log("we have data",index,data)
                console.log(this.currrentMonth[index])
                this.nativeStorage.setItem(this.currrentMonth[index], data);
                this.nativeStorage.remove(this.currrentMonth[index]);
            },
            error => {
                console.log("nextMonthData",index,error)
            }
        )
    }
}
currrentMonth = ["monthData" , "NewspaperMonthData", "MaidMonthData"   ];
nextMonth = ["nextMonthData", "nextMonthNewsData", "MaidNextMonthData"   ];
```

the problem with the above code is, every time in native it falls to error block,

If i directly use the name i am able to shift data could someone help me to fix this

this is my console
[image]

Comment: What is the error logged in the error block?

Comment: added an image @scipper

Comment: as the console log shows, this.currentMonth[index] is undefined. index is 3 in this faulty iteration, and currentMonth only has 3 items (max index of 3).